# How to avoid compiler errors that private fields populated during construction "may be null"

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

A very simple example but often you have private class fields or properties set during construction, and want to pull this out into helper methods:

```
class MyClass
{
 private List<int> _list;

 public MyClass()
 {
  PopulateList();
 }

 private void PopulateList()
 {
  _list = new(){1,2,3};
 }
}
```

Because `_list` is populated in a separate method rather than in the constructor, the compiler gives a warning *"CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable."*

This is correct, but as developer I know the field will not be null. I don't want to make it nullable to appease the compiler, or disable NRTs and null-checking generally, and I don't want to move the contents of `PopulateList` into the ctor as it gets messy.

Other than disable the warning (`#pragma warning disable CS8618`) does C# provide any way to inform the compiler "it's OK"? Or do we simply have to work around this limitation in the compiler's ability to check for null?

Comment: what about adding `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>` in csproj file?

Comment: @letsdoit "**I don't want to** make it nullable to appease the compiler, **or disable NRTs and null-checking generally**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: note: another approach you could use here would be `private readonly List<int> _list = new();` with `PopulateList()` doing `_list.Clear(); _list.Add(1); _list.Add(2); _list.Add(3);` - there are sometimes advantages to knowing the field can't change reference unexpectedly, and it would side-step this scenario; you could also make `PopulateList()` be a `static` method that *returns* the new list, and use `_list = PopulateList();`

Comment: “ This is correct” I don’t think it is correct, the variable does contain a non-null value when exiting constructor; basically that’s the reason I stopped using nullable - there are also false positives for settings, POCOs, something else… - probably there are also attributes like [IKnowThisPropertyIsNotNull] but then big part of the code has those attributes, which doesn’t look nice.

Comment: @MarcGravell I could also do `_list = PopulateList()` and change it to create and return the object, I guess - but only in cases with a single field per method. I think your answer is the definitive answer to "is there a language workaround" in any case

Comment: `but only in cases with a single field per method.` You can return a tuple if you need to initialise more items, but this quickly becomes unwieldy (I have done this for two or three items). The big advantage is that you can make the fields `readonly` if you initialise them this way.

Comment: @MatthewWatson quite - I would typically take "returns a tuple" as a code smell though I do use it for private methods sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```cs
    [MemberNotNull(nameof(_list))]
    private void PopulateList()
    {
        _list = new() { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
```

Comment: I've never even seen this feature before, it seems C# is changing faster than I can learn - thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Boy it would be nice if the compiler could detect it for us, but that quickly gets into "halting problem" levels of hard